# How to find a value within a minimum and and a maximum in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

If I have a minimum salary field and a maximum salary field saved on a record in a database, how could I query if a given number is between those two fields, or in that range, etc?

Comment: so does the table look like attributes*|minSalary|maxSalary|currentSalary, and if so are you looking to validate minSalary<=currentSalary<=maxSalary? Or are you looking to create a proc that takes in 2 arguments @ maxSalary and @ minSalary and queries a table looking like attributes*|currentSalary, returning entries that fit your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from Salaries where @salary between MinSalary and MaxSalary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE salary BETWEEN min_salary and max_salary
```

WHERE salery may be anvy literal value or column, min_selery and max_salery beeing your columns.

Comment: +1 But Drew, this is SQL ABC my friend, if you cant do this on your own even by using _">=min_salary AND <= max_salary_" how can you actually go on with more compex queries?

Comment: yea, was having a brain fart. thx for pointing that out though

Comment: typo alert: it's `salary` - not `salery` or `selery` (that sounds like a vegetable....)